# Tree view wp-admin terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I need to manage a large number of terms for custom taxonomy, is it possible to display terms in treeview or accordion

Comment: Yes, the term administration pages already do this by indenting child terms.

Comment: but indentation is really long if you have many children categories, What i am trying to achieve is more like expanding tree structure or accordion so only top-level are visible by default

Comment: Can you expand then on how this question would be answered? Are you looking for a recommendation? This is a programming stack, and questions need to be specific but this looks more like a general request for recommendations